# Difference between [UINavigationController setView] and [UINavigationController setViewControllers]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a method, which is supposed to init a navigation controller and load a view controller for a side menu. This all happens within a view controller that's not attached to any other navigation controllers.

```
- (void)showLeftNC
{
    if (leftNavCon == nil)
    {
        leftNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    }

    [leftNavCon setViewControllers:@[lmvc] animated:NO];

    //[leftNavCon setView:lmvc.view];

    [leftNavCon.view setFrame:lmvc.view.frame];

    [self.view addSubview:leftNavCon.view];

    [self showCenterViewWithShadow:YES withOffset:-2];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:leftNavCon.view];
}
```

leftNavCon is the navigation controller

lmvc is the primary view controller

It doesn't work in this way, neither when I call initWithRootViewController:lmvc

It only has worked when I used the commented [leftNavCon setView:lmvc.view]. But even then I couldn't get the navigation controller to push any another view controllers yet.

Help please.

Comment: `[leftNavCon setView:lmvc.view]` means that you set the UINavigationController's view to lmvc's view. I guess the pushed viewController'view after you ran the code will be below the UINavigationController's view. Are you sure that `[leftNavCon setViewControllers:@[lmvc] animated:NO];` is not working? I always do this.

Comment: it's working now but I used a view controller as a container for the navigation controller as it couldn't be invoked alone to addSubView

Answer (score 0):

never mind, i worked out something, I used lmvc as a containing view, initialised the navigation controller and all the view controllers i needed inside it

in the lmvc initWithNibName

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        if (testViewController == nil)
        {
            testViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        }

        if (navCon == nil)
        {
            navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: testViewController];
        }

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 748)];

        [self setView:navCon.view];

        [testViewController.view addSubview:table];
        [testViewController.view addSubview:button];
        [testViewController.view addSubview:anyControlYouNeed];
}
```

and then later on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableTwo == nil)
    {
        tabl = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:table.frame];
    }

    if (testViewControllerTwo == nil)
    {
        testViewControllerTwo = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    }

    tableTwo.delegate = self;
    tableTwo.dataSource = self;
    [testViewControllerTwo setView:tableTwo];

    [navCon pushViewController: testViewControllerTwo animated:YES];
}
```

Works like a charm